# Writing a shell wrapper script for awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to embed an awk script inside a shell script but I have trouble to do so as I don't know where to end a statement with a ; and where not.

Here's my script

```
#!/bin/sh

awk='

BEGIN {FS = ",?+" }

# removes all backspaces preceded by any char except _
function format() {
    gsub("[^_]\b", "")
}

function getOptions() {
    getline
    format() 

    print
}

{
    format()

    if ($0 ~ /^SYNOPSIS$/ {
        getOptions()
        next            
    }

    if ($0  /^[ \t]+--?[A-Za-z0-9]+/) {
        print $0
    }
}

END { print "\n" }'

path='/usr/share/man/man1'
list=$(ls $path)

for item in $list
do
    echo "Command: $item"
    zcat $path$item | nroff -man | awk "$awk"
done > opts
```

I'm using nawk by the way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for causing a lot of confusion here ^^... first of all, I posted the wrong version of the script, which is corrected by now... second, the script now works :-)... the reason was that i forgot to put $awk in double quotes, that always gave me a syntax error on the first line of the script...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they provided great insight ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things wrong, as far as I can see:

1. You don't close the multi-line string being assigned to `$awk`.  You need a single quote on the line after `END { ... }`
2. You don't seem to actually *use* `$awk` anywhere.  Perhaps you meant on the invocation of awk inside the `do` loop.
3. Once you fix those issues, `awk` is usually fairly forgiving about semicolons, but any problems in that regard don't have anything to do with using it inside a shell script.

Answer (score 3):

These three lines:

```
path='/usr/share/man/man1'

list=$(ls $path)

for item in $list
```

Need to be changed into:

```
path='/usr/share/man/man1'

for item in $path/*
```

in case there are spaces in filenames and since `ls` is not intended to be used in this way.

Comment: After this good change, `$path$item` should be just `$item`. And also, the variable expansions should be quoted. So, `zcat "$item" | nroff -man | awk "$awk"`

Answer (score 1):

i am not really sure what you meant, but if i understand you correctly, your showOpts.awk is that awk code at the beginning of your script, so you could do this

```
path='/usr/share/man/man1'
list=$(ls $path)

for item in $list
do
    echo "Command: $item"
    zcat $path$item | nroff -man | nawk ' BEGIN {FS = ",?+" }
# removes all backspaces preceded by any char except _
function format() {
    gsub("[^_]\b", "")
}

function getOptions() {
    getline
    format()

    print
}

{
    format()

    if ($0 ~ /^SYNOPSIS$/ {
        getOptions()
        next
    }

    if ($0  /^[ \t]+--?[A-Za-z0-9]+/) {
        print $0
    }
}

END { print "\n" } '
done >> opts
```

and you should probably use >> instead of > .

Comment: I'd suggest that embedding the literal awk program into the loop like that makes the entire shell script very hard to read. Assigning it to a variable first (like the OP was trying to do) and then invoking `awk "$awk"` is much more readable.

Comment: Since the redirect is outside the loop, there's no reason that it has to be an append.